# Is that possible to pass data to different activity using intent but not start that particular activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to pass data to another activity but doesn't want to start the new activity.
Is it possible? If yes then how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is that make a static variable in the other activity. You can set the data from previous activity to the new activity by simply setting this variable value.

```
class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static String variable = null;

}

class OldActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void xxxx(){
        NewActivity.variable = "something";
    }

}
```

But Note that static variable approach is bad.
If you really need this approach, then make it null when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is in term of activity or intent I don't think so it is possible..
if you want to pass data with intent you have to start activity.

1)If you want to do some task without UI then Create service from your first activty.

2)Or you can save that data to some static variable and then use it in you second activity.